# Why can't I add Stereoscopic 3D to my game?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

When I try to develop a game or make a sequel, I can't use Stereoscopic 3D and am limited to just the other options.

I've tried making new engines, loading old saves, rebooting my computer, and even making another game, hoping the graphics option would reappear, but it never does. Why can't I add Stereoscopic 3D to my game, and what do I have to do so that I can?

Comment: I had this issue. I then realized Stereoscopic 3D is an "add-on" to a base 3D engine. You _need_ a 3D engine to add Stereoscopic 3D on top.

Answer (score 3):

Stereoscopic 3D is something that you add during the final development phase. If you use 3D in your game and have researched stereoscopic 3D, you should be able to select this feature just like any other feature you would add to your game (ie. Soundtrack, Level Editor, Voice Aciting, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few limitations on what features you can pile into a game.  First is the position of the slider. If the slider is not positioned high enough, the next to the function name on the right (in this case, "Graphics") you will see a percentage.  In that case you need to move the slider up until the percentage disappears.  On the left hand side you have your employee workload and it might be impossible to program all the features without overworking the employee. My understanding is that the game will let you overwork employees but they will not produce as well.

Finally, it might be impossible to add all the features that you want, even with the slider at its maximum. In that case you need a better employee with high tech, design and probably expert training.  This will happen if you are trying to add 3D V4 and Stereoscopic 3D.